# How to redirect List of URLs stored in a database using HAProxy?

Tags: database, url-routing, redirect, haproxy

I have a list of old and corresponding new URLs stored in a database. I want to redirect the user from old to new URL at HAProxy level.

Comment: How often does this list of URLs change?  Also, a URL includes (at least) scheme, host, path, and query string... at what level of granularity will you be redirecting?

Comment: The list is updated occasionally. The url will be a complete with host, path and query params. redirection would be done to a different url with different path and query params.